# /etc/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000001" has written only

Tags: nginx, git

I have bare repository under NGINX + spawn-fcgi.

Now I'm trying add local directory to remote Git:

```
$ git init
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ git remote add zeus http:/domain.com/new.git
$ git push zeus master
Counting objects: 5483, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5343/5343), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 500 | 2.82 MiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (5483/5483), 463.89 MiB | 19.33 MiB/s, done.
Total 5483 (delta 1591), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

In NGINX error log I have:

> 32015/03/03 12:51:55 [crit] 21530#0: *1 writev()
>   "/etc/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000001" has written only 4671 of
>   8184, client: 10.249.140.96, server: domain.com, request:
>   "POST /new.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "domain.com"

NGINX config:

```
    location / {

        client_max_body_size 0;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /var/gitrepo;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER         $remote_user;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Solved issue, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047752/git-adding-files-to-repo)